# Matching and replacing columns

Tags: awk

I am trying to match the first two columns of two files and replace values of a single column with another column if there is a match.

If columns 1 & 2 of file1 match 1 & 2 of file2 then I want to replace the 2nd column of file1 with the 3rd column of file 2. I initially was using awk but I was not sure how to match two columns from each file and not just one:

`awk -vOFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;a[$2]=$3; next}{$1=a[$1]; $2=a[$2]; print}' file2.txt file1.txt`

Thank you in advance for the help!

file1:

```
112 name1 aaaaa

111 name1 aaaaa

122 name2 bbbbb

133 name3 ccccc
```

file2:

```
111 name1 sarah

122 name2 brittany

133 name3 tony
```

current output:

```
    sarah   aaaaa

111 sarah   aaaaa

122 brittany    bbbbb

133 tony    ccccc
```

expected output:

```
112 name1 aaaaa

111 sarah aaaaa

122 brittany bbbbb

133 tony ccccc
```

Comment: Do the blank lines belong to the files?

Comment: I accidentally added the blank lines but the answers provided worked without them thankfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR {a[$1,$2] = $3; next} {if (length(a[$1,$2])) $2 = a[$1,$2]} 1' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Output:

```
112     name1   aaaaa

111     sarah   aaaaa

122     brittany        bbbbb

133     tony    ccccc
```

(preserving the blank lines in between as is)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {array[$1]=$3; next} {if ($1 ~ array[$1]) print $0; if ($1 !~ array[$1]) print $1, array[$1], $NF}' file2 file1
112 name1 aaaaa

111 sarah aaaaa

122 brittany bbbbb

133 tony ccccc
```